# How to convert c3js charts into png?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, png

I have gone through this links-
https://d3export.housegordon.org/
https://github.com/c3js/c3/issues/313
but I don't understand how to convert. Please provide simple example to convert c3js charts into png image.

Comment: please see this [link](http://bl.ocks.org/biovisualize/8187844)

Comment: its helpful,but I want example using c3js chart

Comment: check this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/c3js/c3js$20to$20png|sort:relevance/c3js/5r3ZYof7xVg/Dw5XKMCJHAAJ) once